# AngularJS: Error when using ui-sref

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting an error when using `ui-sref`

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/home

AngularJS version - `Angular#1.7.3`

ui.router version - `angular-ui-router#^1.0.20`

html code:

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
    <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="signup">Signup</a></li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>

<footer></footer>
```

app.js

```
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url : '/home',
            templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
            controller : 'homeCtrl'
        })

        .state('login', {
            url : '/login',
            templateUrl : 'views/login.html',
            controller : 'loginCtrl'
        })

        .state('signup', {
            url : '/signup',
            templateUrl : 'views/signup.html',
            controller : 'signupCtrl'
        })

});
```

When I removing `ui-sref` in HTML, I am not getting any errors.

When I remove `ui-sref` for home, Then I will get an error for login, like

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/login

I found similar questions in StackOverflow. I tried all the solutions. But none rectified my error.

Comment: what's the `ui.router` version? Do you have any `data-toggle` in HTML?

Comment: can you pls add more code?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey ui.router version: angular-ui-router#^1.0.20
I am not using data-toggle

Comment: @RakeshBurbure I updated the code.

Comment: @praveenkumar [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9SNbAsjFkJXs29SHKGeV?p=preview) works fine with your code and your lib versions. Maybe you can capitalise on that and see if you still find your issue.

Comment: @tanmay I tried with the versions, Still getting the same error